# Smarty variable to be accessed anywhere

Tags: php, module, overriding, smarty, prestashop-1.5

I assigned the variable $my_variable to smarty in my_module:

```
global $smarty;
$smarty->assign('my_variable', self::get_code());
```

get_code() is a function in my_module class that returns a string.

The value inside {$my_variable} is accessible inside my_module.tpl which is hooked in one of PrestaShop's pages.

How can I display/access this smarty variable {$my_variable} from a controller and inside the template page where my_module.tpl is hooked?

Answer (score 0):

You should simple may use:

```
{$my_variable}
```

inside template page.

And in controller you may use it using

```
$smarty->getTemplateVars('my_variable');
```

Of course it may not working if you set it later than using your controller or running your template so you should do somewhere before launching controller.

Comment: {$my_variable} is not available in the template unless I call it inside my_module.tpl, and when I call $smarty->getTemplateVars('my_variable'); inside the controller, it returns 1.

I tried to override the FrontController class and called the function $my_arr = self::$smarty->getTemplateVars();
print_r($my_arr);

The override is working because when I return parent::displayHeader(); the header is displayed twice with all the values assigned to $smarty. However, I was not able to get my assigned variable $my_variable.